# React Shopping Cart: What I am doing wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my products/cart component. It fetches data from a simple json array. But for some reason after adding the items to the cart, I am unable to view them, But I do see in the console that something is adding when I click the add to cart button.
So what I see here is instead of the actual products, I see blank spaces for the products. I will post pictures below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Prod from "../products/ProductsList.json";
import Brands from "./Brands";

export default function Products() {
const [productstate] = useState(Prod)  
const showPage = "page";
const showCart = "cart";
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(showPage);
const addtoCart = (productstate) => {
console.log("Added");
setCart([...cart, productstate]);
};
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const filterPrducts = productstate.filter((item) => {
 return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
});
const returnProducts = () => (
<>
  <h2 className="text-center mt-4 mb-2 font_indie">Shop Featured</h2>

  <div className="row m-1">
    {filterPrducts.map((item, index) => {
      return (
          <div key={index} className="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
            <div className="card h-100">
              <img className="card-img-top" src={item.picture} alt="" />
              <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title h1">{item.name}</h5>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-info"
                  onClick={addtoCart}
                >
                  Add to Cart
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
  <div>
    <div className="row">
      <Brands />
    </div>
  </div>
</>
);
const returnCart = () => (
<>
  <h2 className="text-center mt-5 mb-5 font_indie">Your Cart </h2>
  <h2 className="text-center mt-5 mb-5 font_indie" onClick={() => navigateTo(showPage)}>View 
Products </h2>
  <div className="row m-1">
    {cart.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index} className="col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center">
          <div className="card h-100">
            <img className="card-img-top" src={item.picture} alt="" />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title h1">{item.name}</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
  </>
  );

const navigateTo = (nextpage) => {
setPage(nextpage);
};

return (
<>
  <div className="myCart" onClick={() => navigateTo(showCart)}>
    <span className="btn">
      <i className="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i>({cart.length})
    </span>
  </div>
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="text-center search_bar mt-4">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search items"
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
    {page === showPage && returnProducts()}
    {page === showCart && returnCart()}
  </div>
  </>
  );
}
```

[image 1 is products page, after adding item to the cart I see that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw9fA.png)

[In image two, those odd looking empty boxes are the added products, I see as many boxes as there are in the cart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPoiA.png)

[Here is what i get when i console log the product state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuqhJ.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: We cannot help you with the information that is available right now. Please update the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe on jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: I fixed it. I did not pass that state into my cart that's why. hahah that was a silly error. Thank you tho!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found anything wrong in your code. Do you think it might be a CSS style problem?

Your variable `productstate` is an array or an object?

If it's array, you should spread it.